# azure service bus message Id us email ID

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azureservicebus

I am creating a batch job to read email from an inbox using Microsoft Graph API and publish the content of the email using service bus.
I put a duplicate detection in my azure service bus based on the assigned Message ID. To prevent publishing the same email, I put the Email message Id to the Azure Service Bus Message ID.

However it seems that the length of the email message ID is too long and I am unable to fit it as the azure service bus message ID. Any solution on how to put the email message ID as the Azure Service Bus message ID? (I am not allowed to store the email message ID in any persistence storage, I can only publish it via Azure Service Bus)

Thanks

Comment: The messageid is internally used by Azure service bus and it's not to send emails with Microsoft Graph API as its not a standard email address. It's used for message routing and correlation with Azure service bus only. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads) for it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the service bus message ID can't exceed **128** characters. Generally, the value of
email ids that you retrieved from Microsoft Graph API look like:

```
AAMkADU1NzNkY2I2LWIxY2QtNGFhOC1iYmE5LWEzODA2ZjJkMjQxNwBGAAAAAABRRlt89urpT62rDl3o5R1RBwCSQ84srYEXTY2slhDtcrhrAAAAAAEMAACSQ84srYEXTY2slhDtcrhrAABlQp2FAAA=
```

Generally, its length is **188** characters which caused this issue.

To solve this issue, you can try to use MD5 to create a unified identifier for the email ID, by default, its length will be **32** characters, though this value has the possibility to collision with a hash that from a different string, but its possibility is low(about 2^-128).

If you are using C#, just try the code below:

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace serviceBusTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            string queueName = "";
           
            var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

            ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

            ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage();
            var emailID = "AAMkADU1NzNkY2I2LWIxY2QtNGFhOC1iYmE5LWEzODA2ZjJkMjQxNwBGAAAAAABRRlt89urpT62rDl3o5R1RBwCSQ84srYEXTY2slhDtcrhrAAAAAAEMAACSQ84srYEXTY2slhDtcrhrAABlQp2FAAA=";

            message.MessageId = GetMd5Hash(MD5.Create(), emailID);

            sender.SendMessageAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName);

            ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage = receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage.MessageId);
        }

        static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
        {

            byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));


            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }


            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]